# Firefox moziilla issue in css animation

Tags: css-animations

I have implemented CSS animation to have hover effect. In chrome it is working fine, but in firefox mozilla first time is working but next time there is no animation.

Please guide.

Please refer: http://www.theincredibleindiatourcompany.com.au/

Thanks
Ashish Bajpai

Comment: Please post all relevant code here and/or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: Could you post a code snippet showing just the issue at hand (the barest minimum to illustrate the problem), so it's easier to help without a) visiting your link and b) getting distracted by irrelevant code?